# Swing application failed to start in Java 8 via calling it through JNLP

Tags: java, swing, java-8, weblogic12c, jnlp

I'm migrating a Swing Application from Java 6 to 8. Build and compilation is done successfully but when I deploy it over the WebLogic server and launch the application, I get the error below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/substance/SubstanceLookAndFeel
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.substance.SubstanceLookAndFeel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

[image: getting error when launch the application]

Here is the JNLP file configuration.

```XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp       spec="1.6+"     codebase="http://SERVER_NAME:8080/jnlp/" href="test.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Test</title>
        <vendor>ABC</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <update check="always" policy="always" />
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" max-heap-size="512M" initial-heap-size="256m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <property name="weblogic.MaxMessageSize" value="2000000000"/>
        <!-- Environment -->
        <property name="env" value="test"/>
        <!-- SSO authentication parameters for DEBUGGING -->
        <property name="abc.xyx.debug" value="true"/>
        <property name="aaaa.rrrr.debug" value="true"/>
        <property name="tttt.rrrr.eee.enable" value="true"/>
        <jar href="libs/test-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true"/>
        ..........SOME OTHER JAR's
        <jar href="libs/swingx-0.9.5.jar"/>
        <jar href="libs/swing-worker-1.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="libs/substance-lite-4.3.jar"/>
       
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <nativelib href="libs/XYZ-1.0.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.example.Login" />
</jnlp>
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be the root cause of this issue, why it's throwing `NoClassDefFoundEroor`?

P.S. Same build is working fine with Java 6 and it is also working with Java 8 when I execute the application from Eclipse (Run as Java Application).

Comment: The error means that class `SubstanceLookAndFeel` was in the CLASSPATH when you compiled your application but it is not in the CLASSPATH when you run your application. If you packaged your application into a JAR file, then you probably need to add the `Class-Path` header to the JAR manifest file. By the way, please don't post images of errors. Copy and paste the text.

Comment: @Abra: Its a WAR file and I added the Class-Path in the manifest file and still facing the same error.

Comment: Do you see any errors downloading the jar files? Add `deployment.trace=true` and `deployment.trace.level=all` to your `deployment.properties` file. By default, Java downloads all the jars eagerly. The `Class-Path` inside the jar should be ignored by deployment stack; try to remove it from all the jars and, when launching locally, add all the required jar files via `-cp`: `java -cp libs/substance-lite-4.3.jar;libs/swing-worker-1.1.jar;...;libs/test-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.Login`. This would be closer to what deployment stack is using.